# Wordpress GET parameters causing 404 Not Found

Tags: php, 404-error

all, I'm having a problem with my wordpress page while using encrypted $_GET parameters to obtain data. this is my function:

```
function encryptDecrypt($key, $string, $decrypt)
{
    if($decrypt)
    {
        $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "6");
        return $decrypted;
    }else{
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
        return $encrypted;
    }
}
```

I'm using the registered user's mail to encrypt it and to retrieve his data using $_GET parameter. The problem is that if i use the normal email address (not encrypted, which it will be quite useless and dangerous) the $_GET request works. If i use an encrypted email, I only get a 404 Error.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$m=urlencode(encryptDecrypt('mail',$mail,false));    
$msg.="<br><a href='siteurl/pageurl/?m=".$m."'>Click here</a>";
```

Example of encrypted mail which is used in the URL to send data:

```
VOvk4Wh%2FpMzm21lQNrFnvBcwRWLw6ZVPOMe0VCi2t3g%3D
```

and, in the "retrieving" page:

```
urldecode($_GET['m']);
```

Example of encrypted mail which is used in the URL to retrieve data:

```
VOvk4Wh/pMzm21lQNrFnvBcwRWLw6ZVPOMe0VCi2t3g=
```

When i open the "receiving" page with that link i get the 404 Error

**UPDATE**+

I've solved the problem, which was the 'm' as $_GET parameter, which is a wordpress's default taxonomy... Thanks to you all for helping me. :)

Comment: Did you add a Query Var for it? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

Comment: Should I use it? That page is only intended to be a "black-on-white" page with some text to be printed... The funny thing is that if i write `siteurl/pageurl/?m=foo`or `?m=bar` or `?m=wololoooo` it works...

Comment: I've found the problem!

Comment: I just had the same problem but I was using `?name=`. You can find a list of all the [reserved terms here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms)

Answer (score 9):

As the OP found out, `m` is a reserved parameter name that should be use only by core (indicates month). Solution is to use some other parameter name (always use your own prefixes in all global contexts!).

Comment: Many of us discover this the hard way ;-)

Comment: I just found out that `year` is also reserved...

Answer (score 2):

I just found out I had a `post_type` with the same name as the query string.

For instance, if you had a post_type called `news`, this query string would return a 404: `?news=foo`, even if you have pretty permalinks enabled.

You can either rename the post type or the query string.

Answer (score 0):

first off; turn the wp_debug function on if you haven't already. (wp_config.php). This should give you some additional error data. Secondly; it looks like you are using *urldecode*, but not encoding your string. If you're including an email address be sure to *urlencode* your data as well.

Comment: i use `urlencode` to write the string on the `a` tag's `href` and then, on that page, i use `urldecode` to retrieve the original string... By the way, if I get a 404 Error the problem should be on the "link writing" function, or am I missing something? WP_DEBUG is already enabled

Comment: Hi sorry, I overlooked that. The solution is easier I think :) If the link you posted is the code you are really using then the problem lies with the quote '"'. 

`<a href="siteurl/page/?m="<?php echo urlencode(encryptDecrypt('mail',$mail,false)); ?>">`

you are closing the quotes when addding the php part.

Comment: try: `<a href="siteurl/page/?m=<?php echo urlencode(encryptDecrypt('mail',$mail,false)); ?>">`

Comment: Isn't it the same thing as I've done so far?

Comment: In your code there is a closing double quote (") after `...?/m"`. This says that your url ends there. However, in your link there is more to come. Check the source code of the link in your browser. It will look messed up.

Comment: try the replacement code I posted earlier. It will work (the link part at least)

Comment: No, sorry, my fault, I forgot it. The 'a' tag is written on PHP, so the quotes are right (href is actually right). I've updated my question, I'm sorry